# How to split value

Tags: php, split

I want to split value.

```
$value = "code1.code2.code3.code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)";
```

I want to split like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => code1
    [1] => code2
    [2] => code3
    [3] => code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)
)
```

I used explode('.', $value) but explode split in parentheses value. I don't want split in parentheses value. 
How can i do?

Comment: Are you planing to break down the `code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)` part in the next step? I.e. do you want to write a more or less complete parser anyway?

Comment: @VolkerK i want to simple parser. Only a line parse.

Comment: What about `(arg1.arg2, arg3)` shouldn't it be `(arg1, arg2, arg3)` ? Also what about this `code*` things. Are they going to have the same name maybe with different numbers attached (like in your example) or is it arbitrary? If all this is the case I have a working solution... but I am just not sure.

Comment: Yeah, more details / some real examples would be nice.

Comment: I'm saddened by the preg examples.  =<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need preg_match_all and a recursive regular expression to handle nested parethesis

<s>$re = '~( [^.()]* ( ( ( [^()]+ | (?2) )* ) ) ) | ( [^.()]+ )~x';</s>

```
  $re = '~( [^.()]* ( \( ( [^()]+ | (?2) )* \) ) ) | ( [^.()]+ )~x';
```

test

```
 $value = "code1.code2.code3.code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8).xx.yy(more.and(more.and)more).zz";

 preg_match_all($re, $value, $m, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
 print_r($m[0]);
```

result

```
[0] => code1
[1] => code2
[2] => code3
[3] => code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)
[4] => xx
[5] => yy(more.and(more.and)more)
[6] => zz
```

Comment: This doesn't quite match the output he's looking for.  Check out "code4".

Answer (score 1):

explode has a limit parameter:

```
$array = explode('.', $value, 4);
```

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: probably the easiest if the strings are fixed

Comment: I'm certainly hoping they are!  :)

Answer (score 0):

can you use something other than '.' to separate the codes you want to split on? Otherwise, you require a regex replace.

```
$value = "code1|code2|code3|code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)";
$array = explode('|', $value);

Array
(
    [0] => code1
    [1] => code2
    [2] => code3
    [1] => code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this'll work:

```
function split_value($value) {
    $split_values = array();
    $depth = 0;

    foreach (explode('.', $value) as $chunk) {
        if ($depth === 0) {
            $split_values[] = $chunk;
        } else {
            $split_values[count($split_values) - 1] .= '.' . $chunk;
        }

        $depth += substr_count($chunk, '(');
        $depth -= substr_count($chunk, ')');
    }

    return $split_values;
}

$value = "code1.code2.code3.code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8).code9.code10((code11.code12)).code13";

var_dump(split_value($value));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple parser:

```
$string = "code1.code2.code3.code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)code1.code2.code3.code4(code5.code6(arg1.arg2, arg3), code7.code8)";
$out = array();
$inparen = 0;
$buf = '';
for($i=0; $i<strlen($string); ++$i) {
    if($string[$i] == '(') ++$inparen;
    elseif($string[$i] == ')') --$inparen;

    if($string[$i] == '.' && !$inparen) {
        $out[] = $buf;
        $buf = '';
        continue;
    }
    $buf .= $string[$i];

}
if($buf) $out[] = $buf;
```